# efficient way to print out my format

Tags: go

I wish there is an efficient way to print out my format.
As I know convert to string may occur performance issue.
Is there any better method?

```
package main

import "fmt"

type T struct {
  order_no [5]byte
  qty int32
}
func (t T)String() string {
  return fmt.Sprint("order_no=", t.order_no, 
    "qty=", t.qty)
}

func main() {
        v := T{[5]byte{'A','0','0','0','1'}, 100}

    fmt.Println(v)
}
```

The output is `order_no=[65 48 48 48 49]qty=100`
I wish it will be `order_no=A0001 qty=100`.

BTW, why `func (t T)String() string` work and `func (t *T)String() string` can not work.(on goplay)

Comment: `v` is a `T`, not a `*T`. Therefore, its method set doesn't include methods on `*T` (though a `*T` *does* have the methods of `T`). Go lets you call `*T` methods on `v` anyways (as a special case), but only as long as v is addressable. The value in an interface isn't addressable, so when you pass `v` as an interface parameter to `fmt.Println`, `fmt.Println` can't call a `func (t *T) String() string` on it, but it can call a `func (t T) String() string`. To get around this, you could pass `&v`.

Comment: Thanks, Steve, in my case, should I use fmt.Println(&v) instead of fmt.Println(v) to prevent a copy struct?

Comment: Generally, yes, though you could also declare v as `v := &T{...}` and pass that directly. Sometimes it makes sense to pass around a struct by value, but here, since you're passing it to an interface and it's larger than a machine word, there really isn't one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
package main

import "fmt"

type T struct {
    order_no [5]byte
    qty      int32
}

func (t T) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprint(
        "order_no=", string(t.order_no[:]),
        " qty=", t.qty,
    )
}

func main() {
    v := T{[5]byte{'A', '0', '0', '0', '1'}, 100}
    fmt.Println(v)
}
```

Output:

```
order_no=A0001 qty=100
```

Comment: Does the string() convert create new memory allocate?  If that's a C's null string, can I use the same way?